# Disable Exe From Task Manager

Tags: c#

How can I hide my executable so it doesn't show up in task manager when running?  There are a lot of EXEs running with the same name, and I want to avoid confusing users.

**Update**

OK, fine.  Tell me, how can I disallow the EXE from being killed by others from Task Manager?

Comment: Do you want to prevent a process from being shown in the list of processed displayed by Task Manager?

Comment: The natural question would be why would you want to do that?

Comment: Indeed... there is no legitimate reason to do so.

Comment: Btw, how come it is not shown that there has been an edit to the question?

Answer (score 6):

If you really need to do this, you basically need to use a rootkit.  See the Hoglund & Butler book, "Rootkits: Subverting the Windows Kernel."  But you will be fighting the operating system and the anti-malware vendors every step of the way.

See also Raymond Chen's repeated discussions of "arms races" for why Windows doesn't support this -- basically if you are allowed to remove yourself from Task Manager then users are going to want another utility which shows them hidden processes, and then you are going to want a way to remove yourself from that utility, et cetera ad infinitum.

If you really must do this, by the way, you will need to use C or assembler, not C#.

Answer (score 3):

Google the term "rootkit". Basically, this is considered very evil and is usually only used for evil purposes, therefor this is bad practice since modern antivirus-software would probably flag your software as malware.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rootkit

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your updated question. Make sure that your process runs under the `System` account or similar and make sure that the users don't have `Admin` rights on the pc. They then won't have permission to kill the process.